# I tried to make a C++ Tic Tac Toe game but am not getting the correct output

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I tried to make a c++ program but getting a wrong result every time.

Whenever I assign x and y co ordinates 2 and 3 respectively, it assigns two of the elements as 'X' and not just one. I have tried that many times now.

Code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void reset(char a[2][2])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a[i][j] = '_';
}
void dispmat(char a[2][2])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            cout << a[k][l] << '\t';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void getcoordinates(int &x, int &y)
{
    cout << "Enter the row: "<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the column:" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    x--;
    y--;
}
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char a[2][2],yon = 'y';
    int t = 2,x,y, flag = 0;
    do
    {
        reset(a);
        for(int h = 0; h < 9; h++)      // max no. of cells to be filled = 9
        {
            clrscr();
            dispmat(a);             // displays matrix
            if(t++%2 == 0)          // X's turn
            {
                cout << "It is X \'s chance now" << endl;
                getcoordinates(x,y);
                a[x][y] = 'x';
                for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                    //if any one condition is true, x is declared the winner
                    if((a[m][0] == a[m][1] && a[m][1] == a[m][2] && a[m][2] == 'x')||(a[0][m] == a[1][m]&&a[1][m] == a[2][m] && a[2][m] == 'x')||(a[0][0] == a[1][1]&&a[1][1] == a[2][2] && a[2][2] == 'x')||(a[2][0] == a[1][1]&&a[1][1] == a[0][2] && a[0][2] == 'x'))
                    {
                        flag = -1;   //if flag = 1, x wins
                                 //if flag = -1, 0 wins
                                 // if flag = 0, its a draw
                        break;
                    }
                if (flag == -1||flag == 1)
                    break;
            }
            else              // 0's turn
            {
                cout << "It is 0 \'s chance now" << endl;
                getcoordinates(x,y);
                a[x][y] = '0';
                for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                    if((a[n][0] == a[n][1] && a[n][1] == a[n][2] && a[n][2] == '0')||(a[0][n] == a[1][n]&&a[1][n] == a[2][n] && a[2][n] == '0')||(a[0][0] == a[1][1]&&a[1][1] == a[2][2] && a[2][2] == '0')||(a[2][0] == a[1][1]&&a[1][1] == a[0][2] && a[0][2] == '0'))
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                if(flag == 1)
                    break;

            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
            cout << "Winner is 0!" << endl;
        else if(flag == -1)
            cout << "Winner is X!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "It is a draw!" << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to continue?" << endl;
        cin >> yon;
    } while(yon == 'y' || yon == 'Y');
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: If you have any choice in compilers to use, do not use Turbo C++. That sucker's been obsolete for decades. There are many free alternatives, The Visual Studio Community edition for example, that aren't 30 years out of date.

Comment: I'm not that firm in C++ - but shouldn't you dimension your array "char a[3][3]" instead of "char a[2][2]" if you want to have 3x3 elements?

Comment: I'm lazy today.  When you used the debugger, which statement(s) are causing the issue?  Please edit your post with the information and indicate what the expected variable value is and the actual.

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns an `int` to the operating system.  Always.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews here, the return type of main is **void** hence return statement not required... However with the help of this community and people like you, i was able to solve my tiny error...

Comment: @DhruvTyagi They mean that `int` is the only valid return type for main even if you do not need to specify a return value for it (ignoring platform specific things of course), using `void` invokes undefined behavior potentially as can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is simple: 
You are using a [2][2] array, but you really need a [3][3] array. You do index an array by using [0],[1],[2]... but to define it's actual size, you need to use the maximum index + 1,

so `char a[3][3]` in this case.

Comment: I really had that misconception that array of a[2][2] will have 9 elements with indices 0,1,2 for rows and columns.